# Invalid use of argument matchers! (Mockito)

Tags: mockito

[image: Mockito]

I got an error when I was using Mockito.
I use the matchers for all parameters, but an error has occurred.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please include a clear problem description and if possible some minimal code. For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And take the website tour!

Comment: If you can provide the body of your test code and the error output, perhaps this can be answered.